# Understanding the reasoning for "be killed rather than kill"

Tags: halacha-theory, maseches-sanhedrin, murder, martyr

[Sanhedrin 74a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.74a.20?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) teaches us the source for how we know a person should be killed rather than kill:

> **סברא הוא** [...] מי יימר דדמא דידך סומק טפי דילמא דמא דהוא גברא סומק טפי
>
> **It's based on logical reasoning** (*s'vara*) [...] Who is to say that your blood is redder than his? Perhaps the other person's blood is redder!

**Rashi** there (*s.v.* "[מאי חזית דדמא דידך סומק טפי](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.74a.20?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Sanhedrin.74a.20.3&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en)") explains:

> מי יודע שיהא דמך חביב ונאה ליוצרך יותר מדם חבירך
>
> How do you know that your blood is nicer/ more desirable to your Creator than your friend's?

### My question:

I would understand if this principle was learned out from a *gezeiras hakasuv*, *gezeirah shavah*, *halacha l'Moshe miSinai* etc-- but to attribute the source to "it's logical" (*s'vara*)?

Whereas the aforementioned methods wouldn't leave any room for questioning (ie we'd have an explicit source) **since the source for this principle is  a *s'vara*, couldn't one make the argument that the Gadol Hador's blood is more valuable than that of a huge *rasha's*?**

Comment: IMHO, Svoros are Asmachtos, not sources. It is a very important distinction one should make. It means the claim is NOT *learned* from a Svoro but the Svoro is brought AFTER the decision/ruling was made as an aposteriori justification for the ruling, therefore it can't be questioned logically. In other words, it is just as good as your Svoro, that we CAN make a hierarchy of human values - see Erchin, who's worth more.

Comment: Great question and +1. See discussion below in comments to see if you want to refine the question. This being said, maybe the *gemara* is teaching us one cannot know the true value of someone else in God's eyes. Maybe a *beit din* could make such a judgement but here we are speaking of one person killing someone else to save himself

Comment: FWIW when it comes to a case of two people need tzedakah to live and you can only feed one of them, the Halacha is indeed that you save the Gadol HaDor over the huge rasha: תלמיד חכם ממזר קודם לכהן גדול עם הארץ, from the final Mishnah in Horayos, paskened by Rambam in Hil. Matnos Aniyim 8:18 and by the Shulchan Aruch in YD 251:9.

Answer (score 5):

The definition you present for *svara* is incorrect; it is not arguable. Mahartz Chayus ([Mavo Hatalmud, Ch. 4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mevo_HaTalmud_(Chajes).4.1)) states and proves that *svara* has the same status as the aforementioned methods. Therefore, the *svara* presented in the Talmud cannot be argued upon as you propose and wouldn't leave any room for questioning (ie we have an explicit source).

> עוד יש לנו הרבה ענינים בתורה שבע״פ. אשר לא באו אלינו באחד מאלו אופנים השלשה שהצגנו למעלה רק דרך סברא משקול דעת האדם. וכחו של הלכות אלו גם כן דין תורה ממש להם. 
>   כמו דאמרינן ריש זבחים, ובשאר מקומות, אי בעית אימא סברא, ואי בעית אימא קרא ראינו דקרא וסברא שניהם שקולים הם. הדברים הנטבעים בשכל אנושי ובהקש הדעת, שוים בדרכי הלמד והמתלמד כאלו נלמדו מקראי.

See the part where he discusses your case:

> עד שהתעוררו בש״ס להקשות דהסברא תספיק והקרא מיותר.
>   ויותר מזה תראה (פסחים כ״ה ע״א) דלמדו חז״ל ענין זה ברוצח יהרג ואל יעבור מסברא. מה חזית דדמא דידך סמיק טפי, דילמא דמא דחברך סמיק טפי. וגבי עריות למדו חז״ל שם דיהרוג ואל יעבור מדכתיב כי כאשר יקום איש על רעהו ורצחו נפש כן הדבר הזה. הרי זה בא ללמד ונמצא למד. מה רוצח יהרג ואל יעבור, אף נערה המאורסה יהרג ואל יעבור. ראינו שהתורה עצמה סמכה ענינה דרך הקש ללמד גילוי עריות מרוצח. אשר כל ענינו של רוצח דיהרג ואל יעבור, לא נדע רק מכח סברא. והיינו משום דכח הסברא נכבד 
>   כל כך, עד שהונח ליסוד מוסד ללמוד משם ענין אחר.

Comment: I wouldn't use *"proves"* in this case, it's just his Svoro to justify other Svoros. Can you please elaborate on what he writes/claims because I couldn't understand his point at all. BTW how about translating it into English - I think it is the policy here.

Comment: Sure on the first point. Can’t translate them, כי עמך הסליחה

Comment: I think the OP question is less about the technical "is svara equivalent to the other methods" and more "would an alternative svara be that a good person is more valuable than a bad rasha"?

Comment: @mbloch the OP’s premise is incorrect, and ignoring that is not the correct answer.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel I think the OP wants to better understand the svara. The premise is unrelated to the question

Comment: @mbloch He directly brings it up, however.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel yes you are right. He might want to clarify his question based on the above - or not. That is why we have comments :->

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel thanks for the answer! (would be great if you could translate to English) My understanding is that a "*svara*" teaches us a din that's SO obvious that we don't even need a pasuk/ drasha. My question is it *really* so obvious that one should be killed and not kill? I'm not questioning that we can't- I'm questioning why the gemara assumed this reasoning was so obvious that a pasuk/ drasha wasn't even necessary

Comment: @mbloch thanks for the feedback! what would you suggest I clarify in the question?

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel I think your question is to understand the svara from the Gemara. The equivalence with the other principles is less relevant and generates answers which might be less helpful

Answer (score 2):

The svara is explained in several tosfotim in Shas, e.g. in Yevamot 53b, explaining the Gemara in Sanhedrin.
When one of two men would be killed anyways, and the one of them has a choice to make a criminal act to kill the second man or to do nothing and be killed, we have a svara. His own life isn't more valuable than the life of the second man. So, to make an action which is the sin of killing is not justified because this would not change the fact that one of them will be killed. The change is that he would make a sin. Contrarily if they want to push his body on a neonate and the neonate will die because of this, or to act a suicide to avoid the dead of the neonate, the right choice is to do nothing and let them to push him, because the life of the neonate is not more important than his life. This is a shev veal taase.

Last Tosfot of the amud, continuing in 54a

> ורוצח גופיה קאמר התם דסברא הוא דמאי חזית דדמא דידך סומקא טפי כו' וזה לא שייך אלא במאנסין אותו להרוג בידים אבל אם רוצים לזורקו על התינוק ויתמעך בזה אדרבה איכא למימר איפכא . מאי חזית דדמא דחבריה סומקא טפי כו'‏

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Possible to include a link to that Tosfos?

Answer (score 1):

Rambam, Hil. Yesodei HaTorah 5:5:

> וְכֵן אִם אָמְרוּ לָהֶם עוֹבְדֵי כּוֹכָבִים תְּנוּ לָנוּ אֶחָד מִכֶּם וְנַהַרְגֶּנּוּ וְאִם לָאו נַהֲרֹג כֻּלְּכֶם. יֵהָרְגוּ כֻּלָּם וְאַל יִמְסְרוּ לָהֶם נֶפֶשׁ אַחַת מִיִּשְׂרָאֵל. וְאִם יִחֲדוּהוּ לָהֶם וְאָמְרוּ תְּנוּ לָנוּ פְּלוֹנִי אוֹ נַהֲרֹג אֶת כֻּלְּכֶם. אִם הָיָה מְחֻיָּב מִיתָה כְּשֶׁבַע בֶּן בִּכְרִי יִתְּנוּ אוֹתוֹ לָהֶם. וְאֵין מוֹרִין לָהֶם כֵּן לְכַתְּחִלָּה. וְאִם אֵינוֹ חַיָּב מִיתָה יֵהָרְגוּ כֻּלָּן וְאַל יִמְסְרוּ לָהֶם נֶפֶשׁ אַחַת מִיִּשְׂרָאֵל:
>
> Likewise, if the idolaters say to them, “Give us one of you that we may kill him, and if not, we’ll kill all of you,” let them kill al of them, and not hand over a single Jewish life. But if they single him out, and they say, “Give us so-and-so, or we’ll kill all of you,” if he is liable to the death penalty like Sheva Ben Bichri, give him to them, but we don’t rule to them like this initially. If he is not liable to death, let them kill all of them, and do not hand over a single Jewish life.

Kesef Mishnah ad. loc.:

> כתב הרמ''ך אף על פי שנמצא בתוספתא כדבריו לא ידענא טעמא מאי דהא מסיק בגמרא (פסחים כ''ה) דמש''ה אמרינן בשפיכות דמים יהרג ואל יעבור דסברא הוא מאי חזית דדמא דידך סומק טפי והכא ליכא האי סברא דהא יהרגו כלם והוא עצמו ומוטב שיהרג הוא עצמו ואל יהרגו כולם. ואני אומר שאין טענתו טענה על התוספתא דאיכא למימר דהתם שאני שיחדו לו וא''ל קטול לפלניא ומש''ה אי לאו טעמא דמאי חזית דדמא דידך סומק טפי לא הוה אמרינן דיהרג ואל יעבור והיינו דקתני סיפא יחדוהו להם אבל ברישא שלא יחדוהו שלא אמרו אלא תנו אחד מכם ונהרוג אותו בכל אחד מהם שירצו למסור אותו איכא למימר להו מאי חזיתו שתמסרו את זה תמסרו אחד מכם ותצילו את זה דמאי חזיתו דדמא דהאיך סומק טפי דלמא דמא דהאי סומק טפי וע''פ טענה זו א''א להם למסור שום אחד מהם אבל אי קשיא על ר''ל קשיא דאמר שאע''פ שיחדוהו להם אם אינו חייב מיתה לא ימסרוהו דהא ליכא הכא סברא דמאי חזית דדמא דידך סומק טפי שהרי הוא והם נהרגים אם לא ימסרוהו. ואפשר לומר דס''ל לר''ל שמ''ש דבש''ד סברא הוא אינו עיקר הטעם דקבלה היתה בידם דש''ד יהרג ואל יעבור אלא שנתנו טעם מסברא להיכא דשייך אבל אין ה''נ דאפילו היכא דלא שייך האי טעמא הוי דינא הכי דיהרג ואל יעבור:

In short, he quotes the Ramach, who asks why we don’t apply the general rule that murder is forbidden, based on “what do you see that his blood is redder - maybe your blood is redder.” Seemingly we don’t apply that here, as even if he is included in the group, we still kill all of them according to the Rambam and according to Reish Lakish in Yerushalmi Terumos 8:12, who the Rambam is paskening like.

The Kesef Mishnah takes issue with this argument, saying that without “what do you see,” we wouldn’t require that he be liable to the death penalty when he’s singled out to permit his being handed over. In the first case, where they don’t single anyone out, the logic is that nobody can be handed over, because who can determine who’s blood is “reddest”? The question on Reish Lakish, he says, is the case where he’s singled out but not liable to the death penalty: why don’t we say the fact that he’s singled out makes his blood “redder,” since he’s going to die anyway? Perhaps, he says, **the reason that one must give up his life by murder is not the logic, but a tradition; the logic was later posed to justify the tradition, but the law still holds even when the logic does not.**

The Kesef Mishnah’s conclusion invalidates the premise of your question: as murder being one of the “big three” is derived from oral tradition, not from the logic posed in the Gemara, we still can’t murder even when the logic doesn’t seem to apply.