# List of all the times the principle of "svara" is used in Shas

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, deorayta, svara

There's a principle of "*svara*" in Shas, which exists on a *d'oraisa* level (see this [related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99931/why-is-the-principle-of-svarah-a-source-for-some-halachik-concepts-but-not-other)).

A few examples of *svara*s:

- 1) **המוציא מחברו עליו הראיה** -  "the burden of proof rests upon the claimant" (see "הכלל ומקורו"  [number 3](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%93%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99%D7%AA:%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%90_%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95_%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95_%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%99%D7%94))
- 2) **כל דאלים גבר**- "whoever is stronger prevails" (under [“מקור וטעם”](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%9B%D7%9C_%D7%93%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%92%D7%91%D7%A8))
- 3) **מאי חזית דדמא דידך סומק טפי**- be killed rather than kill (lit: "who says your blood is redder than his etc."- see "[Understanding the reasoning for be killed rather than kill](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106137/understanding-the-reasoning-for-be-killed-rather-than-kill)"

**Does a list exist that has all the instances in Shas where the principle of "*svara*" is used?**
<sub>(additional opinions of *Rishonim* who use "*svara*" to explain a halacha or *din* are also welcome)</sub>

Comment: You forgot הפה שאסר הוא הפה שהיתר. Your first example and this one is where they explicitly say סברה היא

Comment: לאו לאוקמא בכילתא שאילתא - for פטור שואל by מתה מחמת מלאכה